# Constructor not called? Why?

Tags: c++

This is how I create an object, and call some functions:

```
Img *img = new Img(16, 16, 4);
img->set_pixel(10, 10, new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
img->texture_();
```

img.hpp

```
#ifndef Img_HPP
#define Img_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

#include "../obj/texture.hpp"
#include "../obj/color.hpp"
#include "layer.hpp"

using byte = unsigned char;

class Img
{
public:
    byte *data;
    Img(int _width, int _height, int _format);
    void set_pixel(int x, int y, Color* c);
    void add_layer(Layer _layera);
    Texture *texture_();
    ~Img();
private:
    int width, height, format, data_length;
    std::vector<Layer> layers;
};

#endif
```

img.cpp

```
#include "img.hpp"

Img::Img(int _width, int _height, int _format)
{
    std::cout << "initImg\n";
    width = _width;
    height = _height;
    format = _format;
    data_length = width*height*4;
    data = new byte[data_length];
    std::fill_n(data, data_length, 255);
}

void Img::set_pixel(int x, int y, Color *c) {
    if (c->format_() == format) {
        byte *c_bytes = c->bytes_();
        for (int i = 0; i < format; i++) {
            int d_i = (width*y+x)*format+i;
            data[d_i] = c_bytes[i];
        }
    } else {
        //unknown color format: <format>
    }
}

void Img::add_layer(Layer _layer) {
    layers.push_back(_layer);
}

Texture *Img::texture_() {
    std::cout << width << " " << height << " " << format << "\n";
    return new Texture(width, height, format, data);
}

Img::~Img()
{

}
```

When I compile this code I get no errors or warnings. The problem is that when I run it, the constructor of `Img` is not called ("initImg" is not printed to console). Other two functions are called, but the `Img` objects data is not correct. `texture_()` function prints `16 4 1024` to the console, when it should print `16 16 4`. I'm really confused. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Those pointers look mighty unnecessary. `img` and the call to `set_pixel` should be plain objects. `texture_` should return a plain object, unless it has some specific need of a `std::unique_ptr`. `set_pixel` shouldn't take a pointer. `data` should be a `std::vector`. You should use a constructor initializer list as well.

Comment: Please post up a http://sscce.org/ .

Comment: The code looks ok.  What programming environment are you ysing and how exactly are you compiling?  Could you simplify your code down to just one file and one compilation command?

Comment: I suspect the issue lies in code you haven't shown. What is the minimal `main()` that shows the problem?

Comment: Writing `"\n"` to `std::cout` doesn't necessarily flush the stream. If you want to flush the stream so you can read it on the console, insert a [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) instead.

Comment: Just a tip: you don't need to `#include` *any* standard library headers in your header, since the class definition doesn't depend on anything from the standard library. Save build time by not including unnecessary headers. They can be included in the implementation file instead.

Comment: Also, tip #2: you do not need to `new` your object. Just declare it as a variable (note that due to the general extreme efficiency of C++ code, `new` in C++ is relatively *extremely expensive*). All this points in the direction of coming from Java?

Comment: He, I'm really sorry but I was using a wrong library when compiling.. xD

Comment: new and pointers all over the place (even for the tiny Color)

Answer (score 0):

You may not be seeing the printout because you are not flushing standard out:

```
std::cout << "initImg\n";
```

Does not force output, try changing that to:

```
std::cout << "initImg" << std::endl;
```

Standard out will generally only flush if:

You use `endl` or `flush`

You fill its output buffer

The program exits gracefully

So if your program does only a small amount of output and either keeps running, or crashes you should use either `endl` or `flush`.

If that doesn't help, you should step through that code in a debugger.

Comment: I just tested it. Still no output.

Comment: @VitaliusKuchalskis: do present a *complete but minimal* example.

Comment: @VitaliusKuchalskis Have you stepped through a debugger?

Comment: It'd still be printed out when the program ends.